# Sql won't update using web methods and linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql

So im trying to update two tables using DataSets and lists along with c# and SQL  but it wont make any changes this is my code :

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int PercentDone { get; set; }
    public List<BusinessObject> Children { get; set; }
    public int Progress { get; set; }

}
```

This is the class where im trying to update my values :

```
public void Update( List<BusinessObject> Tareas)
        {

        foreach (BusinessObject valor in Tareas)

        {

          int? taskId = valor.Id;


            spCliente_Proyectos_GanttTableAdapter DatosTAS = new spCliente_Proyectos_GanttTableAdapter();
               DSProyectosPlaneacion.spCliente_Proyectos_GanttDataTable DatosTS = DatosTAS.GetDataGantt(idProyecto.Value);
               DSProyectosPlaneacion.spCliente_Proyectos_GanttRow result = DatosTS.FirstOrDefault(sv => sv.id == valor.Id);




            if (result != null)     

                    {

                // result.id = valor.Id;
                  valor.Name = result.sTitulo ;
                  valor.StartDate = result.dFechaI;
                  valor.EndDate = result.dFechaF;
                  valor.PercentDone =(int) result.fAvance;
                }

          DatosTS.AcceptChanges();
        }


    }
```

the web method is defined as follows :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateIt(List<BusinessObject> Tareas)
{
    ListarClientesProyectoGantt Editar = new ListarClientesProyectoGantt();
    Editar.Update(Tareas);

}
```

What am I missing? thank you so much in advance

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `result != null`?

Comment: yes it is I have tested it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're modifying the `valor` variable in your if statement, but I don't see any place where you add `valor` into a data set. If you don't add it to a data set it can't be saved to your DB.

Comment: isn't linq and web method for it ?

Comment: @Chris, I'm sorry but that question doesn't make much sense to me